# Sitemaps in Django

Tags: python, django, sitemap

I'm trying to get the dynamic sitemap generator working in my Django blog. I've followed the directions given [here](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-sitemap-tutorial), I even went so far as to create a new "recipes" project and worked through the tutorial. I got the sitemap to work in the tutorial, but I can't get it to work in my blog. Can anyone help?
Here's the project-level urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path, include
from users import views as user_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.contrib.sitemaps import GenericSitemap
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from blog.models import Post

# from blog.sitemaps import BlogSitemap

info_dict = {
    "queryset": Post.objects.all(),
    "date_field": "date_posted",
}


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # path('register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
    path('profile/', user_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='logout'),

    path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset.html'), name='password_reset'),

    path('password-reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
             template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),

    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
        template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'), name='password_reset_confirm'),

    path('password-reset-complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
        template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete'),

    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),

    # Robots.txt
    path('robots.txt', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='robots.txt', content_type='text/plain')),

    # Sitemap
    # path('sitemap.xml', sitemap, {'sitemaps': {'blog': BlogSitemap}},),
    path("sitemap.xml", sitemap, {"sitemaps": {"blog": GenericSitemap(info_dict)}},),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here's the blog app's urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    PostListView,
    PostDetailView,
    PostCreateView,
    PostUpdateView,
    PostDeleteView,
    UserPostListView
)
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about'),
]

# For the sitemap
urlpatterns += [
    path('<int:pk>', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
]
```

Here is views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.generic import (
        ListView,
        DetailView,
        CreateView,
        UpdateView,
        DeleteView
)
from .models import Post


def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html' # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 3


class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html' # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 3

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'


class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False


class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = '/'

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html', {'title': 'About'})
```

Here is models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        # return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
        return reverse("post-detail", args=[str(self.id)])
```

Here's my sitemaps.py:

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from blog.models import Post


class BlogSitemap(Sitemap):
    def items(self):
        return Post.objects.all()

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        # return obj.updated_at  # or date_posted?
        return obj.date_posted
```

And here's a snippet from settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',

    # Crispy forms
    'crispy_forms',
    'crispy_bootstrap4',

    # Summernote editor
    'django_summernote',
]

SITE_ID = 1
```

Comment: Depending on what you already have done with your project, the `SITE_ID` may not be **1** anymore.  Try changing it to `SITE_ID = 2`, then `SITE_ID = 3`.  See if that makes any difference.

Comment: I voted to close this question because the code sample is too long. Please [edit] your post to reduce your code to a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).